# How to make GridView touchable inside ListView?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-listview, touch-event

I'm trying to implement grid view inside list view. I want to disable touch of List View and want to perform touch event on Grid View. How to do it? 
I need to do this because i have implemented my calendar within grid view and i have inflated my grid view within list view.

I am using below custom List activity to disable scrolling and touch event but still it gets my touch as I am getting log as true value for "ListViewTouch" and "ListViewDispatchTouch".

```
public class ScrollDisabledListView extends ListView {

private int mPosition;

public ScrollDisabledListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ScrollDisabledListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ScrollDisabledListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.d("ListViewTouch", "true");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.d("ListViewDispatchTouch", "true");
    final int actionMasked = ev.getActionMasked() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

    if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Record the position the list the touch landed on
        mPosition = pointToPosition((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY());
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        // Ignore move events
        return true;
    }

    if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // Check if we are still within the same view
        if (pointToPosition((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY()) == mPosition) {
            super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            // Clear pressed state, cancel the action
            setPressed(false);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attribute to the ListView in your layout file: `android:clickable="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Add this in your `gridview`'s `XML` file. That should do it.

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/reminderItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

        android:padding="0dp">
```

Comment: It will only block the descendants in a grid view but my actual touch is being perform on a list view which contains each grid view as a list item

Comment: Have you implemented OnItemClickListener? Do it.

Comment: I want to perform MOVE operation on gridview so i need to implement OnTouchListener on gridview